# Как в postgreSQL изменить значение ключа, который глубоко в jsonb объекте?

Tags: postgresql

В базе PostgreSQL в jsonb хранится объект типа

```
{
  strips: [
    {id: 1, key: 'value'}
  ]
}
```

Как изменить value, зная id? Желательно одной транзакцией.

Comment: Что-то типа `update table set field->'value' = @value where field->'id' = @id`

Answer (score 1):

В `postgresql` есть [список функций](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) обработки `json`, но подчас его немного не хватает. Задачу решить можно, но бывает надо задуматься, а стоит ли её решать именно так и не лучше ли сделать хранимку на каком-нибудь прикладном языке... Впрочем, к делу.

Предположим что речь идёт о таблице `tablename` и jsonb поле в ней `data`. И хотим заменить `key` на `newvalue` у элемента с `id` 1. Сначала напишем `select`, чтобы не трогать данные и можно было сравнить изменения:

```
select data, jsonb_set(data, '{strips}', (
    select jsonb_agg(case when (el->>'id')::int = 1 
        then el || jsonb_build_object('key', 'newvalue') 
        else el 
      end) 
    from jsonb_array_elements(data->'strips') as el)
) from tablename 
where data ? 'strips';
```

Затруднение в том, что у вас в `strips` - массив записей. Поэтому поиск и изменение делается через разворачивание массива в список строк и сборку затем обратно.

И массив же мешает написать эффективное условие `where` для отбора строк. Как с этим можно поизвращаться - пожалуй тема отдельного вопроса.

Переписываем в `update`:

```
update tablename set data = jsonb_set(data, '{strips}', (
    select jsonb_agg(case when (el->>'id')::int = 1 
        then el || jsonb_build_object('key', 'newvalue') 
        else el 
      end) 
    from jsonb_array_elements(data->'strips') as el)
)
where data ? 'strips';
```